# Transform GeoTiff into JPEG under condition of number of bands

Tags: tiff, geotiff, fme

I'm super new to FME.
I have lots of GEOTIFFs which I want to convert to JPEG, which works fine (as seen in the picture below (without the Tester)). But now some of my tiffs have 3 colour and some have 4 colour bands. If the tiff has 4 bands, I can easly remove it. But if it now contains only 3 colour bands it won't run. Therefore I tried including something of a "if more than 3 colour bands then remove them, but if 3 or less then just transform them."

[TIFF-Transformer to JPEG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5lXq.png)

How do I insert this conditional selection?

Answer (score 0):

a reddit user (u/jontyg83) answered my question with the following:

> Try using a rasterbandpropertextractor and a listelementcounter. That should give you the number of bands you can then separate the 3 and 4 band rasters with a tester or testfilter